# Can't resolve crash EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I publish twice my app for iTunesConnect, and twice rejected because of a crash.

This occurs when the user taps on "Contact" tab on iPhone/iPad iOS 8.2, but I tested it on simulator, or real device, and I can't have this crash...

Can you tell me something about that ?

Here is the `crash log` symbolicating :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18237c2d8 0x182254000 + 1213144
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193a9c0e4 0x193a94000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1823833a4 0x182254000 + 1242020
3   CoreFoundation                  0x182380154 0x182254000 + 1229140
4   CoreFoundation                  0x182282ccc 0x182254000 + 191692
5   BundoranSurfCo                  0x1000190a4 -[Contact viewDidLoad] (Contact.m:20)
6   UIKit                           0x186dbcc84 0x186dac000 + 68740
7   UIKit                           0x186dbc994 0x186dac000 + 67988
8   UIKit                           0x186ef2e68 0x186dac000 + 1338984
9   UIKit                           0x186ef2b58 0x186dac000 + 1338200
10  UIKit                           0x186fba378 0x186dac000 + 2155384
11  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
12  UIKit                           0x186fba1cc 0x186dac000 + 2154956
13  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
14  UIKit                           0x186dda4e0 0x186dac000 + 189664
15  UIKit                           0x186fb9e04 0x186dac000 + 2153988
16  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
17  UIKit                           0x186dda4e0 0x186dac000 + 189664
18  UIKit                           0x186df0da0 0x186dac000 + 282016
19  UIKit                           0x186daffc0 0x186dac000 + 16320
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1823342a4 0x182254000 + 918180
21  CoreFoundation                  0x182331230 0x182254000 + 905776
22  CoreFoundation                  0x182331610 0x182254000 + 906768
23  CoreFoundation                  0x18225d2d4 0x182254000 + 37588
24  GraphicsServices                0x18b94b6fc 0x18b940000 + 46844
25  UIKit                           0x186e22fac 0x186dac000 + 487340
26  BundoranSurfCo                  0x10001f4c4 main (main.m:14)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x19411aa08 0x194118000 + 10760
```

and here my code for `Contact.m` :

Line 20 is : `self.fbLikeButton.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;`

```
#import "Contact.h"


@interface Contact ()

@end

@implementation Contact

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.fbLikeButton.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
    self.fbLikeButton.objectID=@"https://www.facebook.com/BundoranSurfco/";

#pragma mark - Google Map API
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 54.481151
                                                            longitude: -8.272278 zoom: 15];
    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
    GMSMarker *marker = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.title = @"Bundoran Surf Co";
    marker.snippet = @"Main Street";
    marker.map = self.mapView;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated] ;
    self.mapView = nil ;
}

- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Contact by BundoranSurfCo App"];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"info@bundoransurfco.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"logo"];
        NSString *emailBody = @"";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)phoneButton:(id)sender {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:071-9841968"]];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Start by symbolicating the crash report.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks man, I edited my code with sybolicating crash report

Comment: Try setting camera to nil in line 5 and see if you get the crash.

Comment: @MichaelL Thanks for reply, but the symbolicating crash report says in line 20 (fbLikeButton) and I know why now :  « FBLikeControl is a preview feature and may not be deployed to the App Store. Only developers and testers of your Facebook app will be able to use the Like Button. »

Comment: @xcode_Dev Thanks for reporting back. You should give that as an answer to your own question, as it may be useful to others!

Answer (score 1):

Crash report says that the problem is in line 20 (`fbLikeButton`) and I know why now :

`« FBLikeControl is a preview feature and may not be deployed to the App Store. Only developers and testers of your Facebook app will be able to use the Like Button. »`

So App crash and is rejected by Apple.